# R, AWS Windows, CRAN packages installation

Tags: r, windows, amazon-web-services, package, cran

I have an AWS (Amazon Web Services) virtual machine, and it is a Windows machine.
I downloaded R and installed (R-2.7.2-win32).
When I tried to install a CRAN package,

> install.packages("rcdk")

I always got massage like:

> “Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.7”

I guess the AWS server restricted R accessing the internet. 
I went to firewall “Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall”, and I allowed “R for Windows front-end” to access Private and Public firewall. It did not solve the problem.

How can I configure AWS windows, so R can install packages?

Comment: The current version of R is 3.2.5. Did you really install 2.7? That's very out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess the AWS server restricted R accessing the internet

**Absolutely not: AWS does not filter such resources.**

Your problem is simply that https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib only contains versions **2.13, 2.14, 2.15, 2.16, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4 and 3.5**.

So, you have 2 solutions:

- either change your remote repository witch such an utility as `install.packages` to point to an old repository that could contain an archive of the 2.7 version (see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository)
- or, easier, remove your relatively old R-2.7.2-win32 and install something more recent, **at least version 2.13**, on your Windows host at AWS.

Comment: You are right. I uninstalled version 2.7, and reinstalled R 3.4. The problem was solved. Thank you very much.